# Reference a variable from another method objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm very new to Obj-C, so apologies if the question is fairly obvious!

Anyway, I'm just getting into objective-c and trying to create a basic iOS counter, where each time the user clicks/touches the UI, a point counter is incremented.

I have created the currentScore int and can log that to the console. I also log successfully each touch of the UI to console.

What I'm now trying to do is, access the currentScore int on each touch, and increment the int by 1.

As I say, probably very easy, but not 100% sure how to reference other variables in other functions!

Thanks in advance.

```
//
//  JPMyScene.m
//

#import "JPMyScene.h"

@implementation JPMyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        //Initiate a integer point counter, at 0.

        int currentScore = 0;
        NSLog(@"Your score is: %d", currentScore);

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        NSLog(@"Tap, tap, tap");

        //TODO: For each tap, increment currentScore int by 1

    }
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

}

@end
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change currentScore variable as Global variable like in this code.

```
//
//  JPMyScene.m
//

#import "JPMyScene.h"

@implementation JPMyScene
int currentScore = 0;
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
            /* Setup your scene here */

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        //Initiate a integer point counter, at 0.


        NSLog(@"Your score is: %d", currentScore);

    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        NSLog(@"Tap, tap, tap");
        currentScore++;
       NSLog(@"Your score is: %d", currentScore);
        //TODO: For each tap, increment currentScore int by 1

    }
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

}

@end
```

Comment: Global variables? Please don't teach stuff like this to beginners in OOP, things can easily get out of their hand. BTW, a static one would have had the same effect, but without the nasty "globaliness".

Answer (score 1):

First declare your integer as global variable or property in your interface .h interface. Then access and modify from anywhere you want. Here is your interface and implementation:

```
@interface JPMyScene
{
int currentScore;
}
@end

@implementation JPMyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        currentScore = 0;
        NSLog(@"Your score is: %d", currentScore);
    }
  return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

     for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        NSLog(@"Tap, tap, tap");
        currentScore++;
     }
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to ObjC but to OOP in general. Basically you need a variable that is available in multiple methods of an object. The solution is to declare currentScore as an instance variable of JPMyScene.